# Debug.WriteLine() in C# - What does it do?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was wondering what `Debug.WriteLine()` does. I see it all the time in many different codes, but I don't get what it's supposed to do.

What I found out so far:

> "Writes information about the debug to the trace listeners in the
>   Listeners collection."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will show the message/text in your output window at the bottom of Visual Studio, you can log with it some actions like "Constructor just started" then it is easier to find where error appeared. Another thing is that you can add variables to your debug output like:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Debug message:Shop.Add.Product({0})", Product);
```

Check it here: [Debug.WriteLine Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline)

Comment: Note, if 'Product' above is of string type, instead the WriteLine(String, String) overload is selected causing the raw formatting string to be output.

Comment: So is it same as Console.log() ?

Answer (score 5):

This can be used to trace or log messages in debug versions. It is only executed if your program is compiled as debug version (with the `DEBUG` symbol defined).

You can create own `TraceListener`s to catch the messages and log them as you need. In order to do that, you have to inherit from the abstract [`TraceListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracelistener) class:

```
public class MyListener : TraceListener
{
    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        // log to file or db or whatever you need
    }
    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        // log to file or db or whatever you need
    }
}
```

Then you have to register an instance of your listener:

```
public static void Main()
{
     MyListener listener = new MyListener();
     Debug.Listeners.Add(listener);
     
     // this ends up in MyListener.WriteLine, but only in a debug version
     Debug.WriteLine("This is a debug log message");

     Debug.Listeners.Remove(listener);
}
```

Further reading: [How to: Create and Initialize Trace Listeners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-create-and-initialize-trace-listeners)

Visual Studio always adds its own `TraceListener` when debugging and outputs the messages to the output window's debug pane.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works exactly according to what you stated in the question, source for this method looks something like (simplified):

```
public static void WriteLine(string message)
{
    foreach (TraceListener listener in Listeners)
    {
        listener.WriteLine(message);
        if (AutoFlush) 
        {
            listener.Flush();
        }
    }                        
}
```

So it simply calls the `TraceListener.WriteLine` method for each registered [trace listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/trace-listeners), just like `Trace.WriteLine` does. You can register trace listeners [through config files or code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-create-and-initialize-trace-listeners).

The only difference between `Trace.WriteLine` and `Debug.WriteLine` is that they are compiled based on different conditionals:

```
public class Debug
{
    // this will be optimized away if "DEBUG" symbol is not defined 
    // in project build properties
    [System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void WriteLine(string message) { ... }
}

public class Trace
{
    // this will be optimized away if "TRACE" symbol is not defined 
    // in project build properties
    [System.Diagnostics.Conditional("TRACE")]
    public static void WriteLine(string message) { ... }
}
```